# Where do I add my actual program after I establish a Window using WinMain() and WindowProc()? (C++)

Tags: c, api, winapi, window, location

First of all, sorry for my ignorance of the window creation process. Today is actually the first day of my experimenting with it.

I started to code a text based game a few days ago and I have the main menu, and 3 or 4 different functions that control various things with text. I was then advised to look into Windows API and create a window for the program. I have created the window which can be seen here:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); 

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR nCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"WindowClass";
    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    RegisterClass(&wc); 


    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx( //This creats a new instance of a window
      0,                        
      CLASS_NAME,                
      L"MyFirstWindow",          
      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,       
      CW_USEDEFAULT,             
      CW_USEDEFAULT,            
      500,                       
      500,                       
      NULL,                      
      NULL,                      
      hInstance,                 
      NULL);                


    if(hwnd == 0)
        return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd,nCmdShow); 
    nCmdShow = 1; 

    MSG msg = { };
    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
    return 0;
 }

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:PostQuitMessage(0); return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
            FillRect(hdc,&ps.rcPaint,(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+5)); 
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }return 0;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            if(MessageBox(hwnd,L"Do you want to exit?",L"Exit",MB_OKCANCEL)==IDOK)
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }   return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam); 
}
```

This looks a bit messy, but you probably will not need it anyway.

So at this point I have my original program and this program that creates a window. My question is how, or even where, do I put my original program's code so that it can be incorporated into the window.

If you are reading this and thinking I'm a total moron for doing it this way, I'm open to ideas that are a lot simpler than what I'm doing right now.

Comment: Windows applications are event-based. You can't directly port a console app to a Windows app without rethinking its design. There's no place to just dump your old code, that's why you can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is the standard boilerplate for creating a window using c and win32 API functions. I recommend that you modify the message pump (it's the while loop in middle calling GetMessage). Instead do this:

1. Run an infinite loop
2. Peek a message
3. If the message is not there, execute your code
4. Else process messages including the quit message

Here's what the code should look like:

```
while (1)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else 
    {
        //Your game code
    }
}
```

I also want to point, that while learning game programming using C and calling Win32 API is a worthy goal, you might want to look at XNA game studio.

The reason I am recommending it is because it is easier to learn and you can make much more interesting games faster. Here are a few links to get you started if you are interested.

http://joshua-w-wise78.livejournal.com/

http://www.krissteele.net/blogdetails.aspx?id=72

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/xna1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203894.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your original program was a console app, that read input and printed output, then you will probably want to get input from your window to implement your game.

Instead of looking at it from the perspective of read user input from stdin then generate output to stdout, you have to think of it from the view of window messaging. So you need to process the WM_KEYDOWN messages, you can then use DrawText() to show the user input in your client area, or you could use a c++ RichEdit control. Once you process the WM_KEYDOWN messages you know what the user has pressed and then your program can do it's thing (maybe being triggered to process an accumalated buffer of characters whenever the WM_KEYDOWN key is equal to the enter key?) and write the output to your client area using DrawText() or send WM_KEYDOWN messages to your richedit window using SendMessage().

I think this is what you meant by a text based game, anyway, you just have to start thinking of doing everything by monitoring windows messages. Anything that the user does to your  window, Windows will send a message to it to let it know.